# d3.json() function results

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to adapt the code from this [basic Sankey example](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/sankey_basic.html) to a local JSON file I generated. It worked fine with a tiny example, but now I'm stuck with these error messages:

> Error:  attribute height: A negative value is not valid. ("-40")

I can see that this is about the node height, which is defined like this in the example code:

```
.attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
```

I don't have much experience with JavaScript and didn't even know where that value was coming from, so I added a `console.log()` first thing after loading the data like so:

```
d3.json("myfile.json", function(error, graph) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(graph);
```

This works and shows me that, in addition to the data that I have in my file (looking similar to [the example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_sankey.json)) there are other values generated: dx, dy, and color. All the dy values are negative, and I don't understand why, or how they are generated in the first place. Can someone please explain this?